# Why no more validation exceptions after invalid child element

Tags: c#, xml

When validating the following xml using XmlReader and a ValidationEventHandler, two validation errors should be reported but only one is. The first excepton message contains  "invalid child element" because the newbook element is not in the schema. 
But the missing "genre" attribute in the first book element is not reported.This is not right, all validation errors should be reported. There is nothing in the W3C Schema specification that says validation should stop after a validation error occurs.  Searching Google I found several reports of similar behavior validating xml in .Net.  When I step through the code in the debugger, the XmlReader correctly reads every node to the end of the file so the reader is able to correctly parse the entire file.

Anyone know why the validation stops?

```
<bookstore xmlns="http://www.contoso.com/books">
 <newbook />
  <book publicationdate="1981-03-22" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
      <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>8.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1967-11-17" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Melville</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>11.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="philosophy" publicationdate="1991-02-15" ISBN="1-861001-57-6">
    <title>The Gorgias</title>
    <author>
      <name>Plato</name>
    </author>
    <price>9.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>

The following is the schema that validates the example XML document.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.contoso.com/books" 

xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="bookstore">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="book">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="author">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="first-name" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="last-name" type="xs:string" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="genre" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="publicationdate" type="xs:date" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="ISBN" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

class XmlSchemaSetExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlReaderSettings booksSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        booksSettings.Schemas.Add("http://www.contoso.com/books", "contosoBooks.xsd");
        booksSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        booksSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(booksSettingsValidationEventHandler);

        XmlReader books = XmlReader.Create("contosoBooks.xml", booksSettings);

        while (books.Read()) { }
    }

    static void booksSettingsValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
        {
            Console.Write("WARNING: ");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        else if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
        {
            Console.Write("ERROR: ");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post [*minimal but complete*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that demonstrate the problem

Comment: example code and files added.

Comment: The following SO discussion is consistent with my question and suggests that this is a .NET issue -not a bug, but just the way MS decided to handle schema validation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314799/should-net-xml-schema-validation-stop-upon-reaching-first-invalid-element.I also found that Java, jaxp specifically, does not behave this  way -it reports all validation exceptions regardless of their scope in the document. You can verify it using this jaxp online validator: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/

Comment: " There is nothing in the W3C Schema specification that says validation should stop after a validation error occurs" - is there something that says it shouldn't stop after confirming the document is invalid?

Comment: Chris -no, but it seems like a bad practice, especially since the online validation tool at the w3c website does not behave this way -it reports all validation errors. It was written in Java and I have found another online java validator that reports all the errors. So there is no technical reason to not report all validation errors.